# Access properties and methods of a class while configuring EntityType in Formbuilder::add()

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I`ve got a dropdown list in my Symfony2 form like this:

```
$builder->add('categories','entity', array(
            'class'     => 'MyBundle:Myentity',
            'property'  => 'name',
            'label'     => 'Mylabel',
            'expanded'  => false,
            'multiple'  => false,
            'label_attr'   =>  array ( 'class'      => 'control-label' ),
            'attr'   =>  array  (   'class'         => 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder'   => 'Placeholder',
                                    'title'         => "Mytitle",
                                    'data-toggle'   => 'tooltip',
                                    'data-myidfromDB'   => '????',
                                    'data-mynamefromDB'=>'????' etc. )));
```

So I am getting a list of MyBundle:Myentity objects and when I choose one I want to show all its properties (like ID, name, etc.) which are stored in my DB and described in Entity class, in different html data-* fields. If I select another one from the list I want to see all information related to my newly selected option in HTML (to change dynamically). Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.7 you can set the option `choice_attr` to ChoiceType and set it a callable receiving the choice as an argument.

EntityType inherits this option and the choice in that case is the instantiated entity, so you can write something like :

```
$builder->add('categories','entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:MyEntity',
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => 'Mylabel',
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
    'choice_attr' => function (\AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity $myEntity) {
        return array(
            'data-private-property' => $entity->getPrivateProperty(),
            'data-some-value' => $entity->someMethod(),
        );
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in easy way.
But you can put more information in select label.

Look on 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Yout can put here more field details and get it from your javascript.

Comment: I tried to use `choice-label` but actually got all names of my options in dropdown list replaced with IDs from my DB. In fact I need these IDs to be displayed in HTML code (in options tag). Thank you

Comment: You can also create own rendering for entity_widget, and put in option tag more details. I think there is possiblity to get other field values in twig. Try dump it in `{%- block choice_widget_options -%}` in _vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig_